# Why are my passwords not being hashed?

Tags: express, hash, passwords, bcrypt

With the code below, I am able to successfully add a new user. However, when I look at users in the database, the password is in plain text. Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

In the section where `let newUser = new User`, the password is passed in from the request body. If there are no errors, bcrypt should hash the password and set the `newUser.password` to the hash value, right?

```
//ADD USER Submit POST Route
router.post('/register',
 [
  check('name').isLength({min:1}).trim().withMessage('Name 
required'),
  check('email').isLength({min:1}).trim().withMessage('Email 
required'),
  check('email').isEmail().trim().withMessage('Email is not valid'),
  check('password').isLength({min:1}).withMessage('Password 
required'),
  check('password').custom((value,{req, loc, path}) => {
    if (value !== req.body.password2) {
        // throw error if passwords do not match
        throw new Error("Passwords do not match");
    } else {
        return value;
    }
})
 ],
  (req,res,next)=>{

  let newUser = new User({
  name:req.body.name,
  email:req.body.email,
  username:req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
 });

 const errors = validationResult(req);

 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  console.log(errors);
     res.render('register',
      { 
       newUser:newUser,
       errors: errors.mapped()
      });
   }
   else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            newUser.name = req.body.name;
            newUser.email = req.body.email;
            newUser.username = req.body.username;
            newUser.password = hash;
        })
    })

  newUser.save(err=>{
   if(err)throw err;
   req.flash('success','You are now registered and can log in');
   res.redirect('/users/login');
  });
 }
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you `newUser.save` inside the `bcrypt.hash` callback. The `save` gets hit first and a user is created in database before the `bcrypt` finishes and runs the callback.

Also inside the callback of `bcrypt.hash` you don't need to do the following again:

```
newUser.name = req.body.name;
newUser.email = req.body.email;
newUser.username = req.body.username;
```

Try following:

```
(req,res,next)=>{

  let newUser = new User({
  name:req.body.name,
  email:req.body.email,
  username:req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
 });

 const errors = validationResult(req);

 if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
  console.log(errors);
     res.render('register',
      { 
       newUser:newUser,
       errors: errors.mapped()
      });
   }
   else{
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(err=>{
               if(err)throw err;
               req.flash('success','You are now registered and can log in');
               res.redirect('/users/login');
            });
        })
    })
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, what you posted makes sense and the passwords are being hashed now.